# how to union the tables in big query

Tags: google-bigquery

```
select a,b,c from(SELECT max(modifiedtime) a FROM tabl1 ),
(SELECT max(modifiedtime) b FROM tabl2 ),
(SELECT max(modifiedtime) c FROM tabl3  ) ;
```

working fine but...output is like..
Row

```
      a                  b              c    
1   1421906942814      null            null  
2   null               1421906942814   null  
3   null               null            1421906942817
```

but I want to print data like

```
     a            b              c 
1421906942814     1421906942814     1421906942817
```

how to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know you need to use a dummykey (even if it's a constant) to be able to do the JOIN on it.

This works:

```
SELECT t1.value,
       t2.value,
       t3.value
FROM
  (SELECT 1 AS dummykey,
          'max1' AS value) t1
JOIN
  (SELECT 1 AS dummykey,
          'max2' AS value) t2 ON t1.dummykey=t2.dummykey
JOIN
  (SELECT 1 AS dummykey,
          'max3' AS value) t3 ON t1.dummykey=t3.dummykey
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  SELECT
  (SELECT max(modifiedtime)
   FROM tabl1) a,
  (SELECT max(modifiedtime)
   FROM tabl2) b,
  (SELECT max(modifiedtime)
   FROM tabl3) c;
```

Comment: This subselect syntax in BigQuery is not possible, you get: `Subselect not allowed in SELECT clause`

Answer (score 0):

I would do CROSS JOIN between them:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT max(modifiedtime) FROM tabl1) a
    CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT max(modifiedtime) FROM tabl2) b
    CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT max(modifiedtime) FROM tabl3) c;
```